# jQuery calculation return NaN on change input text

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have this code to make some calculation when I change the inputs fields:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret vanzare</label>
    <input id="price_vanzare" type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="<?php echo $product->price; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret achizitie</label>
    <input id="price_achizitie" type="text" name="price_achizitie" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="<?php echo $product->price_achizitie; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret transport</label>
    <input id="price_transport" type="text" name="price_transport" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="<?php echo $product->price_transport; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profit net</label>
    <input id="profit" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(":input[type='text']").keyup(function(){ 
    
        var pret_achizitie = $('#price_achizitie').val();
        var pret_vanzare   = $('#price_vanzare').val();
        var pret_transport = $('#price_transport').val();

        var profit_net = ((pret_vanzare - ((pret_achizitie*1.19) + pret_transport + (0.19 * pret_transport))) - ((pret_vanzare * 0.19/1.19) - ((pret_achizitie * 0.19)+(pret_transport * 0.19)))) - (1/100) * (pret_vanzare -(pret_vanzare * 0.19/1.19));    
                
        $('#profit').val(parseFloat(profit_net).toFixed(2));

    } );
```

Before keyup I have:

```
var pret_achizitie = <?php echo $product->price_achizitie; ?>;
var pret_vanzare   = <?php echo $product->price; ?>;
var pret_transport = <?php echo $product->price_transport; ?>;
var transport_client = <?php echo $product->transport_client; ?>;

var profit_net = ((pret_vanzare - ((pret_achizitie*1.19) + pret_transport + (0.19 * pret_transport))) - ((pret_vanzare * 0.19/1.19) - ((pret_achizitie * 0.19)+(pret_transport * 0.19)))) - (1/100) * (pret_vanzare -(pret_vanzare * 0.19/1.19));    
$('#profit').val(parseFloat(profit_net).toFixed(2));
```

and everything is working fine but when I change something is returned NaN for #profit input ID

If I change on `var profit_net` and put only `pret_vanzare - pret_achizitie` it working even I change inputs for pret_vanzare or pret_achizitie

I don't know what is wrong in `var profit_net` because there is something wrong!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], specifically the relevant HTML

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$pret_achizitie =1;
$pret_vanzare = 2;
$pret_transport = 3;
$transport_client = 4;
?>

<script>
var pret_achizitie = <?php echo $pret_achizitie; ?>;
var pret_vanzare = <?php echo $pret_vanzare; ?>;
var pret_transport = <?php echo $pret_transport; ?>;
var transport_client = <?php echo $transport_client; ?>;

 if (!isNaN(pret_achizitie) && !isNaN(pret_vanzare) && 
!isNaN(pret_transport) && !isNaN(transport_client)) {
var net_profit = pret_vanzare - ((pret_achizitie * 1.19) + 
 pret_transport + (0.19 * pret_transport)) - ((pret_vanzare * 0.19 / 
1.19) - ((pret_achizitie * 0.19) + (pret_transport * 0.19))) - (1 / 100) 
* (pret_vanzare - (pret_vanzare * 0.19 / 1.19));

    document.write("Net Profit: " + parseFloat(net_profit).toFixed(2));
} 
</script>
```

i am using this in w3school php compiler its working please check in
your code. and if your value save in input then use

```
          $('#profit').val(parseFloat(net_profit).toFixed(2));
other wise use   $('#profit').html(parseFloat(net_profit).toFixed(2)); 
or 
  $('#profit').text(parseFloat(net_profit).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

While getting values from your `input` you should be parsing it to `float` or `int` to convert your input values to `number`. Try like below and it should work. Also you may use `$('#price_achizitie').val() || 0` so that in case your input is `empty` then it won't return `NaN`.

```
var pret_achizitie = parseFloat($('#price_achizitie').val() || 0);
var pret_vanzare   = parseFloat($('#price_vanzare').val() || 0);
var pret_transport = parseFloat($('#price_transport').val() || 0);
```

Try it here.

```js
$(":input[type='text']").keyup(function() {
  var pret_achizitie = parseFloat($('#price_achizitie').val() || 0);
  var pret_vanzare = parseFloat($('#price_vanzare').val() || 0);
  var pret_transport = parseFloat($('#price_transport').val() || 0);
 
  var profit_net = ((pret_vanzare - ((pret_achizitie * 1.19) + pret_transport + (0.19 * pret_transport))) - ((pret_vanzare * 0.19 / 1.19) - ((pret_achizitie * 0.19) + (pret_transport * 0.19)))) - (1 / 100) * (pret_vanzare - (pret_vanzare * 0.19 / 1.19));

  $('#profit').val(parseFloat(profit_net).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret vanzare</label>
    <input id="price_vanzare" type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret achizitie</label>
    <input id="price_achizitie" type="text" name="price_achizitie" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pret transport</label>
    <input id="price_transport" type="text" name="price_transport" class="form-control" placeholder="Product price" value="3">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profit net</label>
    <input id="profit" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```